# livewire no actualiza el valor de la variable

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire

Apenas conozco lo `Livewire` y me enfrento al siguiente problema.

Estoy haciendo un sistema de votaciones, en el cual se muestran varios objetos y los usuarios incrementan o reducen el valor del mismo.

La cuaestion es que el sistema de votación funciona correctamente, el problema viene ahora que necesito implementar un filtro, el cual se hace desde un par de botones y estos tienen un valor predeterminado 1, 2 ó 3.

El problema es que al intentar actualizar los productos a traves de estos filtros, no puedo actualizarlo, por una o varias razones.

O bien porque la variable esta protegida `protected`, cuando intento cambiarla a publica, cambiar el tipo y usar `mount` para inicializarla y traer el listado de la base de datos, no actualiza, o viene vacío.

He buscado más cosas y revisado la documentación del componente pero la verdad aplico varias cosas de allí y sigo sin poder hacerlo funcionar.

Aquí el codigo del componente

```
use WithPagination;

protected $objects = [];

public function render()
{
    $this->objects = Objects::with('user')->orderBy('approx_price', 'desc')->paginate(50);

    return view('livewire.voting', ['objects' => $this->objects]);
}
```

Método para filtrar los datos

```
public function filterObjects($price)
{
    $this->objects = Objects::with('user')>where('approx_price', '=', $price)->orderBy('approx_price', 'desc')->paginate(50);
}
```

Muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entiendo que necesitas hacer un filtro para los usuarios.

Para esos casos yo utilizo propiedades computadas de la siguiente manera.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

 protected $queryString = [
    'price' => ['except' => ''],
];


class IndexComponent extends Component
{

  public function getObjectsProperty(){
     return Objects::with('user')
     ->where('approx_price', '=', $this->price)
     ->orderBy('approx_price', 'desc')
     ->paginate(50);
  }


  public function render()
  {
      return view('livewire.index-component');
  }
}
```

Te dejo este [enlace](https://julio-guerrero.medium.com/filtros-de-b%C3%BAsqueda-en-laravel-livewire-bd3ebf6fd59f) donde se realiza de manera mas detallada este proceso.

Comment: Gracias @Julio Guerrero, si no te molesta quisiera preguntarte que lo he probado y funciona sin embargo en moviles ni Android ni iOS funciona cuando los utilizo. gracias

Comment: Hola Adrian, me alegra que funcionara y por otro lado en los moviles que error esta mostrando?

Comment: Hola Julio este mensaje lo veo en consola de desarrolladores, porque en moviles directamente no hace nada. Esto en la consola de chrome

caught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at voting:2060:18)

Cuando accedo a ver mas detalles me sale el codigo y esta linea:

console.warn("Livewire: The published Livewire assets are out of date See: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/installation/")

Lo que dice esta pagina ya lo hice, hay otros componentes en la web y funcionan, pero este no funciona.

Comment: He agregado otra pregunta donde esta el codigo completo, por si quieres darle un vistazo.   https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/595311/componente-livewire-no-trabaja-en-android-ni-ios