# Componente Livewire no trabaja en android ni iOS

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, livewire

Estoy trabajando con laravel y livewire y tengo este código en el componente. Desde la vista hago un wire:model a tres elementos : armesFilter, resourcesFilter, trapsFilter.

El código lo que hace es que toma el valor del elemento que he doy clic en la vista y lo pasa al componente, alli este realiza la consulta y como condicional where toma el valor que le envio, consulta la base de dato con ese condicional y me retorna los elementos que luego los muestro en la vista.

```
 use WithPagination;

    protected $objects = [];
    
    public $resourcesFilter, $armesFilter, $trapsFilter;

    public function render()
    {
        $this->enablingVotingForUsers();

        $objects = Objects::query()
            ->when($this->resourcesFilter, function ($query){
            $query->orWhere('type_id', $this->resourcesFilter);
        })->when($this->armesFilter, function ($query){
            $query->orWhere('type_id', $this->armesFilter);
        })->when($this->trapsFilter, function ($query){
            $query->orWhere('type_id', $this->trapsFilter);
        })->with('user')->orderBy('approx_price', 'desc')->paginate(50);


        return view('livewire.voting', compact('objects'));
    }
```

En pc funciona correctamente, pero en moviles (Android, iOS ) no funciona.

Cuando reviso con herramientas de desarrollador, muestra un error por consola:

```
caught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token (at voting:2060:18)
```

y cuando accedo a ver mas detalles me sale el codigo y esta linea:

`console.warn("Livewire: The published Livewire assets are out of date See: https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/installation/")`

La cuestion es que lo que dice esta pagina ya esta hecho, el sitio tiene otros componentes de livewire heredan de las mismas plantillas y funcionan, pero este no funciona.

Gracias

Comment: Podrias mostrar tu composer.json?

Comment: Gracias Julio, lo he solucionado reejecutado los comandos de la instalación de livewire, parece ser que esto refresco todo lo de la aplicacion, despues de esto ejecute tambien el comando optimize:clear y ha funcionado. Los comando de livewire los ejecute la primera vez que lo instale pero no se que habia pasado con ello ya que me marcaba estos errores.  Saludos

Answer (score 1):

La solución a esto fue re ejecutar los comandos de instalación de livewire, con lo cual ha dejado de dar el problema. Aunque ya tenia cosas que funcionaban correctamente en este nuevo componente, fue en este ultimo componente donde marcaba el error.